# Are php memcached and django memcached storage different?

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

I am trying to implement Caching into my new Django project, the problem here is, the cache is set through a PHP server, and I need to read it from Django code. I am able to set the cache in Django, and read in Django, I can also set the cache in PHP, and read in PHP. But, I am not able to do it cross platform. i.e. I am not able to read the cache set in PHP, in Django and vice versa. Although, If I do a `telnet localhost 11211` and fetch both the keys, I am only able to get the Keys set in PHP.
I have done a `pip install python-memcached` installation to use Memcached with Python.
So, my question is how do I use a common cache server for both Django and PHP?

Here is my PHP snippet

```
$memObj = new Memcached();
$memObj->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$memObj->set('php_key', 'hello php');
var_dump($memObj->get('django_key')); #prints False
echo $memObj->get('php_key'); #prints 'hello php'
```

Following is my Python/Django snippet

In `settings.py`

```
CACHES = {
   'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
      'LOCATION': 'localhost:11211',
   }
}
```

In views,

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set('django_key', 'Hello world')
php_cache = cache.get('php_key')
print(php_cache) # Outputs None
django_cache = cache.get('django_key')
print(django_cache) # Outputs 'Hello world'
```

In ubuntu terminal

```
telnet localhost 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
get php_key
VALUE php_key
hello php
END
get django_key
END
```

Comment: So django_key is not working from memcached shell?

Comment: Yes, only the `php_key` is working in memcached shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the key passed by django to memcached isn't exactly the key that you use in your call to `cache.set`

> the cache key provided by a user is not used verbatim – it is combined
>   with the cache prefix and key version to provide a final cache key. By
>   default, the three parts are joined using colons to produce a final string

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#cache-key-transformation

Either tweak the settings, or create your own [KEY_FUNCTION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-KEY_FUNCTION) to make sure that the PHP keys match the django keys.

Comment: I see, lemmi give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks and all the best with your project